# Violation of Primary Key Constraint on Composite Key

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO tbl_AllParcel
           ([P_ID],[Sub_ID],[X_COORD],[Y_COORD])

VALUES 
       ('0706' , '002' , '579002' , '1167176'),
       ('0706' , '003' , '579013' , '1167153')
```

P_ID and Sub_ID are each primary keys that together form a Composite Key. I get the following error message which I run the above code. Shouldn't the unique value be created by the Composite Key alone?

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl_Parcel'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_AllParcel'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you've already got one of these two in the table for that composite key.

```
'0706' , '002' 
'0706' , '003'
```

Comment: So can SQL server 2008 create Composite Keys that do have not unique individual keys?; what I am trying to achieve in the data above

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting the two rows separately. I bet at least one fails, but not necessarily both. The failure is not coming from the data that is only found in the insert statement, unless you have both a composite primary key / unique constraint and another unique constraint on the individual columns.

Also can you explain how you have two primary keys that together form a composite key? A table can only have one primary key. Can you script out the table definition (right-click in Object Explorer in SSMS, Script Table As, Create To, Clipboard), and add it to the question, so we can agree on terminology?

If you have a unique constraint on P_ID and a unique constraint on Sub_ID, then you can only have one of *each* value in the table, as opposed to what I think you intend (only the combination has to be unique). If you have unique constraints on the individual columns, then this is not valid, since it doesn't violate the combined constraint but it does violate the constraint on the first column:

```
P_ID Sub_ID
---- ------
0706 002
0706 003
```

We can tell you how to fix this (and confirm that there isn't already a row with P_ID = '0706' and Sub_ID = either '002' or '003'). What happens when you say this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl_AllParcel WHERE P_ID = '0706' AND Sub_ID = '002';
```

? Or more importantly, I suppose, depending on the script you provide:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl_AllParcel WHERE P_ID   = '0706';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl_AllParcel WHERE Sub_ID = '002';
```

In order to create a composite key without adding keys to individual columns, you don't select individual columns. Here is a way to do this using `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_AllParcel2
(
  P_Id   CHAR(4),
  Sub_Id CHAR(3),
  ... other columns,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Parcel PRIMARY KEY(P_Id, Sub_Id)
);
```

I assume you're using the UI currently. Don't try and do this in the table designer - it's a hunk of garbage. Learn the DDL, It will get you a lot farther. Here are the `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` topics in Books Online, which have plenty of examples for defining various constraints and other table attributes:

[CREATE TABLE (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)
[ALTER TABLE (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Aaron! Below is the code CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AllParcel]( [P_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL, [Sub_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL, [X_COORD] [int] NULL, [Y_COORD] [int] NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Parcel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [P_ID] ASC, [Sub_ID] ASC

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AllParcel]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_AllParcel_tbl_AllParcel] FOREIGN KEY([P_ID], [Sub_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_AllParcel] ([P_ID], [Sub_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AllParcel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_AllParcel_tbl_AllParcel]
GO

Comment: The result of the query is one record. You are certainly right in what you stated especially the comment in the 3rd paragraph concerning my intention. I just don't know anyother way to create a composite key without putting a primary key constraint on the individual keys. Please tell me I was wrong!

Comment: Based on the code you submitted in a comment (sorry I didn't see that before I edited the post), it seems you already have a composite PK. However the script possibly doesn't include unique indexes or unique constraints on individual columns. The data you're trying to insert in the question doesn't work because one of the rows already exists. If you want to have all valid rows inserted, then separate them into individual inserts instead of using the combined VALUES() clause.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I have no other choice but to restructure the key constraints within the db.

Comment: Also consider dropping the tbl_ prefix. It doesn't really help you and just creates extra typing. :-)